# Filtering category objects in a template?

Tags: templating

So I have a Commerce product template page that grabs products something like this (segment 3 is the category slug):

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getSegment(3)).first() %}

{% set product = craft.commerce.products({
    relatedTo: category,
    status: 'live',
}).first() %}
```

However, I need this page to 404 if the category slug isn't in a collection of categories that are chosen in a global field:

```
{% for category in myGlobal.liveCategories %}
    These categories, like this one {{ category.title }}, are the only categories that are allowed right now
{% endfor %}
```

So I want to filter

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getSegment(3)).first() %}
```

against my global category field:

```
myGlobal.liveCategories
```

so that only the `category` that gets passed to my product loop is a valid category in the global set. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish, but this code block doesn't work:

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getSegment(3)).first() %}

{% if category not in myGlobal.liveCategories %}
    {% redirect 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

I assume I have to do some twig filtering, or create arrays and combine, ...or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
{% set ids = myGlobal.liveCategories.ids() %}
{% set category = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getSegment(3)).id(ids).first() %} 
{% if category %} 
    The category is valid 
{% else %} 
    No slug found, or the category is not in the list 
{% endif %}
```

Explanation: you grab all the ids from your allowed categories and search for them in your query. If a category is found it is one of the allowed categories. If not the category is another one or the there is no element with a matching slug.

Comment: Brilliant and does exactly what I needed. Thank you!